# Opencart product option type to the order email

Tags: php, opencart

How would I modify the order email so that it adds the file to the order email?

When I check the code in Account/Download this requires that the user is logged in to be able to view downloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I would not suggest to send big files through an email You have to edit the `Order model` and it's method `confirm` in `/catalog/model/checkout/order.php` - somewhere around line 500 there is a sending of email about just created order to a client.

Here You can get the file for download and add it as attachment.

**EDIT:** You do not need to change the download method. That would break the "My account" section where the downloads are listed, I guess. The only thing You have to do is to load the file(s) that should included (attached) into (to) the order email, attach it and send the email... If user still wants to go and download the file from Your eshop, he still has to log in - but that's normal behavior and I wouldn't change it.

Comment: That's the easy part. Let says I restrict the order upload to only small images. I presume I would need to change the download() method because both of these require the user to be logged in

Comment: Yeah thats what I am asking. I need to be able to change how OC works by default so that I can add an image to the email with being logged in. I know this is going to be a lot of extra code although I just wanted to hear your guys ideas on the best way to implement this.